# How to export the output of SQL query to excel using powershell

Tags: sql, excel, powershell

I am trying to export the result of SQL to excel sheet. below is my query.

```
function Get-SQLData {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$db_server,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$sql_query,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$database_name,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$user_name,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$password
    )
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $db_server; Database = $($database_name); User ID = $user_name ; Password = $password;"
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $sql_query
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
              
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
              
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | Out-Null
              
    $SqlConnection.Close()
              
    return $DataSet
}
$db_name = 'emp';
$user_name = 'deploy' ; $password= 'deploy#1';"
$sql_query1 = "select * from emp;"
$report_path = "D:\Newfolder" 
$SendMail = 0
$report_files = @()

try {
        $output1 = Get-SQLData -db_server $db_server -sql_query $sql_query1 -database_name $db_name -user_name $user_name -password $password
        for ($k=0;$k -lt $output1.tables.count;$k++){
        [Array]$outputArray = $output1.tables[$k]
        if ($outputArray.count -ge 0 ) 
    {
            $report_file = $report_path.ToString()+"Report_File_"+($k+1)+".csv"
            $outputArray | Export-Csv -Path $report_file -NoTypeInformation
            $report_files += $report_file
            $html1 = $outputArray | ConvertTo-Html -head $HeaderStyle 
        }
}
catch{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Error $ErrorMessage
}
```

while printing the $output1 I am getting the below

> RemotingFormat          : Xml SchemaSerializationMode : IncludeSchema
> CaseSensitive           : False DefaultViewManager      :
> {System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor} EnforceConstraints
> : True DataSetName             : NewDataSet Namespace               :
> Prefix                  :  ExtendedProperties      : {} HasErrors
> : False IsInitialized           : True Locale                  : en-US
> Site                    :  Relations               : {} Tables
> : {System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow
> System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow
> System.Data.DataRow
> System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow,
> System.Data.DataRow} Container               :  DesignMode
> : False ContainsListCollection  : True

But excel sheet is not creating in the mentioned location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ImportExcel module from the PSgallery:

```
Install-Module ImportExcel,dbatools -Scope CurrentUser
$result = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $db_server -Query 'select * from emp;'
$result | Export-Excel -Path empl.xlsx -WorksheetName Empl -TableName Empl
```

In this example, I use 2 modules. You really need ony Export-Excel for your needs but DBATOOLS really make this code easier to read.